# calculation of points for each student. two columns' calculations are based each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I want to calculate the remaining points in sql server using cte or any other method

in calculation formula : see the attatched picture.
total points 100
i have used row Count using cte for each student.

```
Row_no  |st_id  |plenty |weekBonus  |weekbenformula |remaining_Points
1       |1      |5      |0          |0              |95
2       |1      |3      |2          |2              |94
3       |1      |2      |0          |0              |92
4       |1      |3      |2          |6              |95
5       |1      |1      |1          |1              |95
6       |1      |3      |1          |1              |93
7       |1      |2      |0          |0              |91
```

Excel example picture is attached.
[image: in excel is it very easy to solve.]

first row calculation for st_id 1: 100 -5 +0= 95

second row calculation for st_id1: 95 - 3 +2=94     here i have to take the previous remaining points. and so on...

or any other solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with recursive cte as shown below. Calculation of `weekbenformula` & `remaining_points` is as per the formula

```
declare @tbl table
(
    row_no            int,
    st_id             int,
    plenty            int,
    weekbonus         int,
    weekbenformula    int,
    remaining_points  int
)

insert into @tbl (row_no, st_id, plenty, weekbonus)
values  (1, 1, 5, 0),
        (2, 1, 3, 2),
        (3, 1, 2, 0),
        (4, 1, 3, 2),
        (5, 1, 1, 1),
        (6, 1, 3, 1),
        (7, 1, 2, 0);

with rcte as
(
    select  row_no, st_id, plenty, weekbonus,
            weekbenformula = 0,
            remaining_points = 95
    from    @tbl
    where   row_no  = 1

    union all

    select  t.row_no, t.st_id, t.plenty, t.weekbonus,
            weekbenformula   = case when r.remaining_points >= 95 then 1 else 3 end 
                             * t.weekbonus,
            remaining_points = r.remaining_points - t.plenty
                             + (case when r.remaining_points >= 95 then 1 else 3 end * t.weekbonus)
    from    rcte r
            inner join @tbl t   on  r.row_no    = t.row_no - 1
)
select  *
from    rcte
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=158a24e1b3cf9a2902b80c7c5416b62a)